# Set CalendarList height dynamically react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to set the height of the CalendarList component based on the structure of the days in active month

I have created a function to determine the correct height of the `CalendarList`

```js
    calendarHeightCalculator() {
        const currentMonth = moment(this.props.calendarStore.currentMonth, "YYYY-MM")

        if (currentMonth.startOf("month").weekday() === 5 && currentMonth.daysInMonth() > 30) {
            return 340
        }
        if (currentMonth.startOf("month").weekday() === 6 && currentMonth.daysInMonth() > 29) {
            return 340
        }
        return 300
    }
```

The function is called each rerender by the CalendarList component through its height property

```js
     <CalendarList
        current={this.state.visibleMonth}
        //onVisibleMonthsChange={this._monthChangeEvent}CalendarList
        pastScrollRange={this.state.scrollRange.past}
        futureScrollRange={this.state.scrollRange.future}
        firstDay={1}
        theme={calendarTheme}
        markingType={'multi-dot'}
        pagingEnabled={true}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        horizontal={true}
        onDayPress={this._selectDate}
        markedDates={this.state.markedDates}
        calendarHeight={sizing.height(280)}
        calendarHeight={this.calendarHeightCalculator()} // <- this is the culprit
        dayComponent={(props) => (<CustomDay {...props} />)}
    />
```

I can confirm that it gets called each rerender and returns the correct height value through extensive use of `console.log`. 
However the `CalendarList` only reacts on the initial value, and ignores the following rerenders?

How can I set the correct height through my `calendarHeightCalculator` function?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the calendar height doesn't trigger a state change and so the calendar won't re-render.

If you want the calendar to re-render change something that actually sets the state on the calendar list.

Take a look at the component to see the props that trigger a re-render [CalendarList.js](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/blob/master/src/calendar-list/index.js)

Comment: The height does not change ON rerender